# How can I run this command succesfully

Tags: command-line, installed-programs, jre

I need to run the following command to run a program in Ubuntu.

```
Java -Dprism.forceGPU=true -jar quantumVITAS-0.1.0.jar
```

I got an error "Java not found"

I have downloaded the last version of JRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu, and Linux in general, is case sensitive. So `java` and `Java` are two different commands. If you installed the latest version of the JRE (and not just downloaded it ;) ), you should have the command `java` available. But it seems you're trying to use the command `Java`, which your system doesn't know about.